# how to calculate hours

Tags: sql, t-sql

i am using sql server 2017.i am calculating hours (reg hours and overtime hours) and i am getting all the hours in reg hours column and if the regular hours is more than 40 it has to go to overtime hours....what is the query here i can use
for example ....in a table i have empid,name,reghou,othours. i got a file from my client with different columns(like name, hours etc) in excel. when i get that excel file the all hours are getting in the hours column. so if i get an hours of 42.83 i want to split it as 40 to the reg hours and 2.83 to the othours. the table should look like the below

[please check the image to know how i want the records as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFKs3.jpg)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Hint: The `-` operator

Comment: question seems doubtable, please provide more information and add some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @EmployeeTimeSheet TABLE(EmployeeID INT, WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO @EmployeeTimeSheet
VALUES(1,8),
(1,8),
(1,8.5),
(2,8),
(2,8),
(1,8),
(3,8),
(1,8.5),
(2,8),
(3,8.5),
(1,8),
(1,8)

SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(WorkedHours) > 40 THEN 40 ELSE SUM(WorkedHours) END as Regular, 
CASE WHEN SUM(WorkedHours) > 40 THEN (SUM(WorkedHours) -40) ELSE 0 END as OverTime 
FROM @EmployeeTimeSheet
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```